# Sequences of particular values MySql Table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to count the number of consecutive rows having a value. To give a simple example, consider 2 dice are thrown which give a value 1-12. I want to get a table of values of the highest sequence of consecutive rows with the same total. Here is a table definition, a stored procedure to populate the table and a command to execute the stored procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE `Dice_throws` (
  `idx` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Dice1` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Dice2` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idx`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
---------------------------------
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertDiceThrows(IN NumRows INT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE i INT;
        SET i = RAND(12345); /* use the same seed */
        SET i = 1;
        START TRANSACTION;
        WHILE i <= NumRows DO
            INSERT INTO Dice_throws(Dice1, Dice2) VALUES (CEIL(RAND() * 6), CEIL(RAND() * 6));
            SET i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;
        COMMIT;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
-----------------------------
call InsertDiceThrows(2000);
```

If select the list of totals (`SELECT Dice1, Dice2, Dice1+Dice2 FROM Dice_throws order by idx;`) then I will get 2000 rows, which may be, for instance `2,5,12,6,7,4,8,8,8,5,11,6,6,`..etc.
At the end of it I want a table something like this:

```
Tot  Seq
1    2
2    2
3    4
4    3
5    7
6    8
7    9
8    4
9    2
10   1
11   2
12   1
```

So this shows that the maximum sequence on consecutive rows where the total was 4 is 3, and 8 consecutive rows where the total was 6 etc. So I want to find the highest sequence of rolls with the same total for each possible outcome.
I can obviously do it in PHP (I have already made it work with PHP) by just selecting the totals then looping through the resultset but I wondered if there is some good way of doing it totally in SQL.
Thanks for any tips or solutions.

Comment: If we randomly populate a table, we're going to end up with a different data set from you. So provide proper INSERT statements and a corresponding desired result. I'm sure we don't need to see 2000 rows. Pretend that it's a single, six-sided die, and I'm sure a couple of dozen rows will suffice. Also, you may want to lock away the following important fact if you take up gambling professionally: the lowest score achievable with two dice is... 2 !!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm not interested in the actual results for any one set, I'm interested in understanding how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
CREATE TABLE test (rid int auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, v int not null);
INSERT test (v) VALUES (2),(2),(3),(3),(3),(2),(4),(4),(4),(4),(4),(4),(2),(2),(2),(2),(1);

SELECT * FROM test;

CREATE TABLE chunks (cid int auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, v int not null, c int not null, s int not null);
INSERT chunks(cid,v,c,s)
SELECT null,t1.v,t1.rid AS c, 0
FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t1.rid=t2.rid-1 AND t1.v=t2.v
WHERE t2.rid IS NULL;

UPDATE chunks c1 LEFT JOIN chunks c2 ON c1.cid=c2.cid+1
SET c1.s=CASE WHEN c2.c IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE c2.c+1 END;
SELECT * FROM chunks;

SELECT v.v,MAX(v.cnt) AS max_cnt
FROM (
  SELECT c.c, MIN(t1.v) AS v, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM test t1
  INNER JOIN chunks c
  ON t1.rid between c.s and c.c
  GROUP BY c.c) v
GROUP BY v.v;
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response, I can see what it's doing.
When I try to run it I get the following:
`Error Code: 1137. Can't reopen table: 'c1'`
on the UPDATE line. I'll fiddle about and see if I've done something wrong.

Comment: What version of mysql do you use? I ran it in mysql 5.5 without any issue.